# TCP Connection Python Scrabble Game

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tcp

I am having issues to properly get this game to run and accept multiple connections at a time. In my `server.py`, there is a print statement within the `while word:` loop that I cannot get to send as a message to the client side. I have been running around trying different things but keep getting `'AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute encode'`.

The print statement scrambles the word. From there, you can make a guess to see what the unscrambled word is.

---

**client.py**

```
import sys
from socket import *              # portable socket interface plus 
constants
serverHost = 'localhost'         
serverPort = 50007                

message = [b'Hello network world']          # default text to send to server
# requires bytes: b'' or str,encode()
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
serverHost = sys.argv[1]                # server from cmd line arg 1

sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)      # make a TCP/IP socket object
sockobj.connect((serverHost, serverPort))   # connect to server machine + port

while True:
# receive line from server: up to 1k
servResponse = sockobj.recv(1024).decode()
if not servResponse:
    break
print(servResponse)
if(servResponse == '\nType your answer: '):     
    nextWord = raw_input('')
    sockobj.send(nextWord.encode())

sockobj.close()
```

---

**server.py**

```
import time, _thread as thread, random
from socket import *

file = open("wordlist.txt", "r")
wordlist = file.readlines()
file.close()

myHost = ''
myPort = 50007

sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sockobj.bind((myHost, myPort))
sockobj.listen(5)


def handleClient(connection):
    word = wordlist[random.randrange(len(wordlist))]
    while len(word) > 5 or len(word) == 0:
        word = wordlist[random.randrange(0, len(wordlist))]
    word = word.rstrip()
    old_word = word
    word = list(word)
    connection.send(("Jumble game starting...").encode())

    while word:
        print(word.pop(random.randrange(len(word))), end=' ')
    connection.send(('\nType your answer: ').encode())
    #connection.send(('Testing: ').encode())
    userAnswer = (connection.recv(1024).decode())
    print('testing')
    new_word = userAnswer + '\n'
    if new_word in wordlist and set(userAnswer) == set(old_word):
        connection.send(("\nYou win.").encode())
    else:
        connection.send(("\nThe word is " + old_word).encode())

    connection.close()


def dispatcher():                                # listen until process killed
    while True:                                  # wait for next connection,
        connection, address = sockobj.accept()
        thread.start_new_thread(handleClient, (connection,))


dispatcher()
```

---

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, does `server.py` or `client.py` throw that error? If `server.py`: that means that `connection.send()` returns `None` at some point.